# Error: contract runner does not support calling

Tags: ethers.js, react

I'm trying to call the `name` function of my smart contract through my React application, but I'm getting the error: `Error: contract runner does not support calling`

`useSigner` hook:

```typescript
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { ISigner } from "@/src/interfaces";
import { useError } from "./useError";
import { parseRPCError } from "../utils";

export const useSigner = (provider: ethers.JsonRpcProvider) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<ISigner>({
    account: undefined,
    balance: undefined,
    network: undefined,
  });

  const { error, setError } = useError();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!provider) return;
      else await requestAccount();
    })();
  }, [provider]);

  const getSignerFromProvider = async () => await provider.getSigner();

  const setSigner = (signer: ISigner) => setValue(signer);

  const requestAccount = async () => {
    try {
      const signer = await getSignerFromProvider();
      const balance = await provider.getBalance(signer.address);
      const network = await provider.getNetwork();

      setSigner({
        account: signer,
        balance: balance.toString(),
        network: network.chainId.toString(),
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      const parsedError = parseRPCError(err);
      setError(parsedError);
    }
  };
  return { signer: value, setSigner, error, setError };
};
```

The page where I'm calling the hook:

```typescript
"use client";

import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import NFTContractABI from "@/src/abi/NFT.json";
import contractsAddresses from "@/src/contracts.json";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { IWrapped } from "@/src/interfaces";
import { withProvider } from "@/src/hoc";
import { useSigner } from "@/src/hooks/useSigner";

const MintNFTPage: FC<IWrapped> = ({ provider }) => {
  const [contracts, setContracts] = useState<any>({});

  const { signer, setSigner } = useSigner(provider);

  useEffect(() => {
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      contractsAddresses.nft,
      NFTContractABI.abi,
      signer.account
    );

    contract.setContracts({ ...contracts, nft: contract });
  }, []);

  const mintNFT = async () => {
    console.log("Starting NFT minting");
    console.log(contracts.nft);
  };
  return <button onClick={mintNFT}>Click here to mint a NFT</button>;
};

export default withProvider(MintNFTPage);
```

And here is where I get the provider:

```typescript
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect, FC } from "react";

import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { Alchemy, Network } from "alchemy-sdk";

import { IWrapped } from "../interfaces";

export const withProvider = (WrappedComponent: FC<IWrapped>) => {
  const EnhancedComponent: FC = (props) => {
    const [provider, setProvider] = useState<ethers.JsonRpcProvider>();
    const [alchemy, setAlchemy] = useState<Alchemy>();

    function createAlchemy() {
      const config = {
        apiKey: process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY,
        network: Network.ETH_GOERLI,
      };

      const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

      return alchemy;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!window.ethereum) {
        alert("Metamask is not installed!");
        return;
      }

      const alch = createAlchemy();
      const prov = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:8545");

      setProvider(prov);
      setAlchemy(alch);
    }, []);

    return (
      <WrappedComponent {...props} provider={provider!} alchemy={alchemy!} />
    );
  };

  return EnhancedComponent;
};
```

I thought that by passing the signer instead of the provider when initializing an instance of a `ethers.Contract` would work, but I guess it's not. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I answered this question on stack exchange...
Here's the link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137839/error-contract-runner-does-not-support-calling-operation-call-code-unsuppor/76540964#76540964